# How do I get commands to execute at an interval?

Tags: bash, networking, intervals

My PC is really messed up, and I need to run `su -c "/etc/init.d/networking restart"` about once every hour. How do I do so? I'm running Ubuntu Server Nov. 2011, and am comfortable with bash. I also have ~4 ttys that are unused, if the process is a while loop.

Thank You in Advance,

ME

Comment: You could use a cron-job.  But really, you should fix whatever it is that's "really messed up"...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm pretty sure it's hardware; I'm using a PC older than my dog, and I've tried reinstalling thrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cron. Thats a time based job scheduler. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I'm confused on what it says to do. Do I just add `@hourly su -c "/etc/init.d/networking restart"` to the end of /etc/crontab? Or are they command arguments?

Comment: No not @hourly but `0 * * * * su -c "/etc/init.d/networking restart"`. Im not sure if you can put su there though. Its been a while since I was using cron. Check the cron.allow as well.

Comment: To schedule a job you edit your crontab. If I recall correctly you can edit it by using `crontab -e` command in your shell.